# Solenoid driver heating issue

Tags: driver, solenoid, pnp

This is regarding an automotive transmission control module(TCM) solenoid driver. The schematic diagram of the driver is very similar to the below image. Only difference is the TCM has the low side switching whereas this schematic has high side switching.

[image]

My problem is the power transistor highlighted in yellow becomes burning hot within one minute of operation. It becomes really hot such that the transistor falls off from the PCB. I don't find any short causing the transistor collector current to exceed its rated value. Is there any other obvious reason why Q3 is getting too hot?

R1 - 3 ohms |
R2,R6 - 47 ohms |
R4 - 18 ohms 10 watt |
Q3 - 2sb1016 |

Comment: That's not how you use a pnp transistor for power switching. I think the transistor goes into linear region, that's why he get so hot. Q3 should directly follow after the 12V source and fully turned on to power the load.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft, that may overheat the solenoid.

Comment: Show the relevant circuit.

Comment: That schematic shows low-side switching - the transistor is on the low (ground) side of the load.

Comment: @Jasen, with fully turned on, I mean not to use it in the linear region. You can stills use pwm then.

Answer (score 1):

> Only difference is the TCM has the low side switching whereas this
>   schematic has high side switching

Erm, no. This schematic has low side switching (Q3 is connected to ground). And

> The schematic diagram of the driver is very similar to the below
>   image.

is not true either. That schematic is not remotely going to work. Since you don't seem to know how transistors in general work, I'm not able to explain it in the course of an answer here.

I'll give you  a starting point though. Assuming that the circuit is designed using high-side switching (and the use of a PNP is a clear indicator that this is so), the schematic should look something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0TsMb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and your Q3 is not possibly an FMMT549 - those are SOT-23s with a maximum current of 1 amp.

As Jasen has answered, your circuit (as drawn) is going to get hot.

Assuming that your actual circuit looks more like mine, I suggest you check for a wrong value on the 47 ohm resistor (it may be too high) or replace Q1.

Another possibility is that Q2 is being partially turned on, with the result that Q1 collector is forced to be more than the ~0.5 V or less which it normally uses to turn on the solenoid is raised to something higher and the base drive to Q3 is reduced. If this is so, Q1 is getting hot, too.

Much more important, provide a real schematic. You seem to have taken an existing schematic and reworked it according to your (mistaken) ideas about how these things work. So until you provide an accurate schematic any suggestions are really just us trying to second-guess you.

Here's a hint - if there really is a high-side/low-side difference between circuits, Q3 needs to be an NPN, not a PNP. And all the rest of the circuit needs changes as well.

Comment: 2sb1016 has TO220Fa package, not SOT

Answer (score 0):

In that circuit it looks like it's supposed to get hot.

R2 and R6 put the base of Q3 at about 6V soon after Q1 has turned on,
so it is dropping 6.6V between E and C with an approximately 2A current flowing.

so that's 13W of heat.  (all number approximate)

The part you have is good for 30W (on a good heatsink) so make sure it has one.